# Как сгенерировать колонку в ag-grid по клику на обработчик

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Задача следующая: необходимо сгенерировать колонку в ag-grid как результат сложения двух других по клику на кнопку-обработчик.
Пример следующий, я передаю через форму данные, которые попадают в базу данных, следом я формирую колонку через ag-grid на основе этих данных. У меня есть мысли как это реализовать путем создания шаблона колонки, который  будет вставляться друг за другом. Но задача - реализовать с помощью ag-grid тк вся математика будет прописана в нем.
Есть ли в api самого грида такая возможность ?
Буду очень благодарен любым идеям.
Заранее спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

Если кто-либо столкнулся с библиотекой ag-grid и стоит задача при заполнении модального окна создать новый столбец с информацией, вот решение (по крайней мере для меня)

```
$('body').on('click', '#include_column', function () { // при клике на "добавить"
  let get_input_name = $('#get_input').val(); //тут я ввожу название столбца
  let columnDefs = context.dataSetTable.myHeader; // колонки моего ag-grid (опционально, по документации там gridOptions.api.columnDefs)

  columnDefs.push({
    headerName: get_input_name,
    type: "VARCHAR2",
  });
    context.dataSetTable.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs); // вставляем в ag-grid           

    $('#modalAdd').modal('hide'); //закрываем модальное окно
    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
    $(".modal-backdrop").modal('hide');
});
```